# Cleared RW (write protect) flag for PTEs of a process in kernel yet no segmentation fault on write

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

I implemented incremental process checkpointing at page level(I just dump the data from the process address space into a file).

The approach I used is as follows. I used two system calls:

1. Complete Checkpoint: copy entire address space. Also if write bit
   is set for a page, clear it.
2. Incremental checkpoint: only dump data if write bit is set and clear it again. So basically, I check if write bit is set for an incremental checkpoint. If yes, dump the page data.

Test program:

```
char a[10000];
sys_cp_range(a,a+10000);
a[3]='A'; 
sys_incr_cp_range(a,a+10000);
```

From what I know, the kernel should be doing page fault and handle illegal write case by killing the process with SIGSEGV. Yet the program is successfully checkpointed. 
What is exactly happening here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you modify a PTE when it's still cached in the TLB, the effect of the modification may be unseen for a while (until the PTE gets evicted from the TLB and has to be reread from the page table).

You need to invalidate the PTE in the TLB with the `invlpg` (I'm assuming x86) instruction after PTE modification. And it has to be done on all CPUs. There must be a dedicated function for this purpose in the kernel.

Also it wouldn't hurt to double check that the compiler didn't reorder or throw away anything from the above code.

Comment: So the modification of a PTE's flags is visible only in the TLB for the time being. On a write protection fault, does the kernel read the entry from the page table and overwrite the entry in the TLB, ignoring the modification in TLB?

Comment: No, why would it do that? The TLB is a cache, why have a cache and ignore it? Makes no sense. Further, you do not directly modify the TLB, except for evicting specific entries from it or flushing the entire cache. The CPU reads PTEs into the TLB when they aren't in there already.

Comment: Ok I think I got it now. When I clear the write bit for a PTE, the changes are reflected in the PTE in the Page table but not in the PTE residing in the TLB(I'm not invalidating the TLB entry). So when PTE is referenced again(for the array modification as well as during second system call), the stale entry in TLB is read which still has the write bit set. Am I right?